# itext7 set font and size of HtmlConverter elements

Tags: itext7

I'm trying to convert some html like a span element and set its font and size

I need to put this paragraph on top of a text area defined in a pdf form.

This is what i do

```
//define style  
PdfFont fontRegular = FindFontInForm(pdf, new PdfName("OpenSans"));
Style regular = new Style(); 
regular.SetFont(fontRegular).SetFontSize(9);

//convert html IList<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(val); 
Paragraph p = (Paragraph)lst[0]; p.AddStyle(regular);

//size of field, need to put html paragraph on top of it 
PdfArray position = toSet.GetWidgets()[0].GetRectangle(); 
float width = (float)(position.GetAsNumber(2).GetValue() - position.GetAsNumber(0).GetValue()); 
float height = (float)(position.GetAsNumber(3).GetValue() - position.GetAsNumber(1).GetValue()); 
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((float)position.GetAsNumber(0).GetValue(), (float)position.GetAsNumber(1).GetValue(), width, height);            

//canvas to add paragraph 
Canvas canvasField = new Canvas(canvas, pdf, rect); 
canvasField.Add(p); 
canvas.Rectangle(rect);
```

But the font is not applied.

Also Could it be possible to set the font and size in the style of a span html element?

Answer (score 4):

Probabbly it is to late but in any case let me tell you how i fixed this.
Basically you are missing following in order to apply the font

```
FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();
provider.AddFont([your font]);

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.SetFontProvider(provider);
```

and then use this:

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(stringToConvert, properties);
```

this way i managed to apply my font to converted html element (paragraph)

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid constructions like this:

```
PdfFont fontRegular = FindFontInForm(pdf, new PdfName("OpenSans"));
Style regular = new Style(); 
regular.SetFont(fontRegular).SetFontSize(9);
//convert html IList<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(val); 
Paragraph p = (Paragraph)lst[0]; p.AddStyle(regular);
```

This is counter-intuitive when converting HTML to PDF.

Instead, I would work with CSS to define the font and the size and the style of a span element. With iText 7, you can now even define different MediaQueries. For instance: if you want the HTML to use one specific set of styles when shown in an HTML browser, but you want to use another set of styles when converting the HTML to PDF, you could work with a `print.css` file.

All of this is explained in the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml).

In [chapter 2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css), you learn how to define styles using CSS. Take a look at this example:

[image]

You see that the text "Read more about this movie" has a smaller font-size. and that "IMDB" has a different font color.

That's because the HTML was defined this way:

```
<div class="imdb">Read more about this movie on
    <a href="www.imdb.com/title/tt4680182">IMDB</a></div>
```

And the CSS was defined this way:

```
.imdb {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
a {
    color: green;
}
```

As you can see, the `<div>` has a `class` attribute `imdb` which is defined in the CSS to have a smaller font size. The CSS for the `<a>`-tag defines that the text color should be green.

All of this is standard HTML and CSS functionality. There's nothing iText-specific here. Whatever is shown in the browser is also shown on the PDF in this case.

The iText code is as simple as this:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
```

Why would you make things complex if it can be as easy as this?

[Chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-3-generating-pdf-based-media-queries) explains what to do if you want to create a difference between what's rendered on the screen and what's rendered on the PDF. We use the `print.css` to achieve this (the PDF will mimic what happens when you print the HTML file).

In your HTML, you might have something like this:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sxsw.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="print only" href="css/sxsw_print.css">
</head>
```

The `sxsw.css` is the CSS that will be used when showing the HTML in a browser; the `print.css` will be used when printing the HTML from the browser. Again there's nothing specific to iText in this HTML. This is common functionality known to any HTML developer.

With iText, the `sxsw.css` will be used if you only use the single line mentioned before. If you want to use the `print.css` instead, you have to change the `ConvertorProperties`:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
MediaDeviceDescription mediaDeviceDescription =
    new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.PRINT);
properties.setMediaDeviceDescription(mediaDeviceDescription);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
    new FileInputStream(src), new FileOutputStream(dest), properties);
```

Now, because we have changed the `MediaDeviceDescription` to `MediaType.PRINT`, the `print.css` styles will be used.

The code is only slightly different if you need the iText elements so that you can add them in a specific rectangle. That's explained in [chapter 1](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf):

```
List<IElement> elements =
    HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(src), properties);
```

You might ask yourself: *Why can't I do it my way? Why shouldn't I define the font size, styles, etc... in my code?*

The answer is simple: *Your code will be hard to maintain! If your employer asks you to apply a change, you will have to change your code, compile it, etc...*

If you do it the way it's described in the official tutorial, it's easy: you don't have to change your code; you only have to change the CSS. That's much easier!

Comment: I'm doing it this way cause working with html and style defined inside this html is not working... the font is not taken into account and the line-heigth is also not correct. Also you are not answering the question as how to set the font used. I don't know why you're explaining the print vs screen thing. it was never mentioned in my question.

Comment: Show us your HTML. Without your HTML, we can't reproduce the problem. As you can tell from the examples in the tutorial, the line heights, fonts families, font styles and font sizes are taken into account. Be aware that you may need to define a `FontProvider` if you want to use a font that isn't provided out-of-the-box. I'm sorry if the *focus* of the question wasn't correct. Maybe that's because the question was unclear. Questions saying "it doesn't work" without extra info are always hard to answer.