# Itext html2pdf use converter for create personal Paragraph

Tags: parsing, itext7, paragraph

But where do you change the font size of the method
HtmlConverter.convertToElements?
Why do I get this result with this code [result code after execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCR78.png) ?
because the text between the tags does not change size ?

I also tried these solutions using the various methods (but the size does not change) :

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59044415/18323778
2. [itext7 set font and size of HtmlConverter elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944486/itext7-set-font-and-size-of-htmlconverter-elements) (In this question it is explained how to use the css too I am interested in changing only 2 properties of the element)

Run this code:

```
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.resolver.font.DefaultFontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Style;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.IElement;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.Property;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author UC9001309
 */
public class TestConvertHtml2pdf {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      
          PdfWriter   pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("C:\\Temp\\" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new java.util.Date()) + ".pdf");
          PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
          Document document = new Document(pdfDocument); 
        
               FontProvider provider =  new DefaultFontProvider(true, false, false); 
            
            
            ConverterProperties cvProp = new ConverterProperties();
            cvProp.setFontProvider(provider);           
            cvProp.setImmediateFlush(true);
            
            List<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.convertToElements("Testo <b><u><i>prova</i></u></b> con tag",cvProp);
                  
            
                  lst.get(0).setProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE,UnitValue.createPointValue(Float.parseFloat("20"))); 
                  
                  Paragraph p = (Paragraph) lst.get(0);
                  p.setProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE,UnitValue.createPointValue(Float.parseFloat("20"))); 
                  
            document.add(p);                   
            document.close();

    }

    }
```

i tried various methods but still don't get results, does anyone know how to fix ?

Thanks for your help .

Comment: why did you remove the previous question that I gave you an answer for? will you continue this pattern of creating questions, getting answers and then removing the questions?

Comment: You're right, I just didn't quite understand how to update the question. I know I have to learn how to use stackoverflow well. I also had a thank you to your comment, because it was the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to create a method in Itext 7 to pass as parameters a string with html tag and font and font size, get it translated by the html parser to apply bold, italics, uderline without setting them with Itex commands as paragraph. selBold ec ..
Because my colleagues get tired of programming.

After several attempts I solved this (I create a main to try):

```
package testconverthtml2pdf;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.resolver.font.DefaultFontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.IElement;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author UC9001309
 */
public class TestConvertHtml2pdf {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      
        // Future parameters of the method change it to test !!!
          float vardim = 10.5f; 
          String tipofont =StandardFonts.COURIER.toString().toLowerCase();
          String strInput = "Testo <b><u><i>prova</i></u></b> con tag";
        // -------------------------------------------------------------    
          
          PdfWriter   pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("C:\\Temp\\" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new java.util.Date()) + ".pdf");
          PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
          Document document = new Document(pdfDocument); 
        

            FontProvider provider =  new DefaultFontProvider(true, false, false); 
             
            ConverterProperties cvProp = new ConverterProperties();
            cvProp.setFontProvider(provider);           
            cvProp.setImmediateFlush(true);
            
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("<p style='font-family:"+tipofont +";font-size:"+UnitValue.createPointValue(vardim)+"'>") ;
            stringBuilder.append(strInput) ;
            stringBuilder.append("</p>") ;
            System.out.println(stringBuilder);
            
            List<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(stringBuilder.toString(),cvProp);
                  Paragraph p = (Paragraph) lst.get(0);
            document.add(p);
            document.close();
    }   
    }
```

To set Font and Font-Size to the input string I add a

with a Style attribute inside for Font and Font-Size taken from parameter.

`stringBuilder.append("<p style='font-family:"+tipofont +";font-size:"+UnitValue.createPointValue(vardim)+"'>") ;`

tipofont  -----> Font parameter
vardim    -----> Font size parameter

I have to thank  [André Lemos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566339/andr%C3%A9-lemos) who in his comment (lost because instead of modifying the question I deleted and recreated) gave me a solution because the bold was not created because the font type that had bold as its attribute was missing. I loaded Currier but not Currier-Bold.

If this solution can help anyone, it is available to the community.